# How Can I Format and Print Column Data Types For Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to generate a Create Table Statement. To do this, I have created 2 procedures to Extract Tables and Columns from my Schema. The Output of these procedures is then spooled to a SQL file and is supposed to look like this:
[The Formatted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qRFn.png)

Right now, My output Looks like this:

```
----
---- Run on October   04, 2020 at 22:00
----
--  Start Extracting table IMAGE
CREATE TABLE IMAGE (

  MFR            CHAR(3,)
, PRODUCT        CHAR(5,)
, IMAGE          BLOB(4000,)
, TECHSPECS      BFILE(530,)
                    );-- END of Table IMAGE creation
--
--
--  Start Extracting table ORDERS
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (

  ORDERNUM       NUMBER(227,0)
, ORDERDATE      DATE(7,)
, CUST           NUMBER(223,0)
, REP            NUMBER(223,0)
, MANUF          CHAR(3,)
, PROD           CHAR(5,)
, QTY            NUMBER(225,0)
, AMOUNT         NUMBER(225,2)
                     );-- END of Table ORDERS creation
--
--
--  Start Extracting table PRODUCTS
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (

  MFR            CHAR(3,)
, PRODUCT        CHAR(5,)
, DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(100,)
, PRICE          NUMBER(225,2)
, QTYONHAND      NUMBER(225,0)
                       );-- END of Table PRODUCTS creation
--
--
---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility V1.0 ----
---- Run on October   04, 2020 at 22:00
```

As you can see, the Data types, along with their Data_length, Data_scale, and DAta_precision are not perfectly formatted as per the requirements. I also haven't been able to make a column that displays the null status of each column. The Date, BFILE, and BLOB as shown in the Output are especially troublesome for me to format properly.

This is my code as of now:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET WRAP OFF

--The Procedure to Extract The Columns
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Extract_Columns (
    --Creating Variables of passed values
    wSee IN OUT varchar2,
    wTable IN USER_TABLES.table_name%type
)
AS
--The Cursor to run through the Columns
CURSOR Extract_C IS
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE, DATA_LENGTH
        FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = wTable
        ORDER BY Column_ID;
        CurrentRow Extract_C%ROWTYPE;

--Creating variables
wItterations NUMBER(1):=0;

BEGIN
      FOR CurrentRow IN Extract_C LOOP
        IF wItterations = 0 THEN  
        
          wsee := wsee || CHR(10) || '  ' || RPAD(currentrow.column_name, 15) || currentrow.data_type || '(' || currentrow.DATA_LENGTH || currentrow.DATA_SCALE || ')';
    ELSE
                wsee := wsee || CHR(10) || ', ' || RPAD(currentrow.column_name, 15) || currentrow.data_type || '(' || currentrow.DATA_LENGTH || currentrow.DATA_PRECISION || ',' || currentRow.DATA_SCALE || ')';
        END IF;
        wItterations:= wItterations +1;
      END LOOP;
END;
/

SHOW ERRORS;

 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Extract_Tables
 AS
        l_crt varchar2(356);
        CURSOR Extract_T IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM USER_TABLES
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
    CurrentRow Extract_T%ROWTYPE;

    --Creating Variables
    wvers VARCHAR2(256) := 'V1.0';
    wcur_Tim VARCHAR2(200) := '' || TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE, 'Month DD, YYYY') || ' at ' || To_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'HH24:MI'); 
    wheader VARCHAR2(45) := 'CREATE TABLE ' || CurrentRow.table_name ||' (';
    wspacing NUMBER := length(wheader);

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wvers || ' ----');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----');       
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- Run on ' || wcur_Tim);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----');


    FOR CurrentRow IN Extract_T LOOP

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--  Start Extracting table ' || CurrentRow.table_name || '');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATE TABLE ' || CurrentRow.table_name ||' (');

          --This is where i should be calling the other procedure
            Extract_Columns(l_crt, CurrentRow.table_name);

            --This is where create tables procedure begins again
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_crt || chr(10) || LPAD(' ', 15 + length(currentrow.Table_name)) || ');' || '-- END of Table ' || currentrow.Table_name || ' creation');



            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--' || CHR(10) || '--' );
          l_crt := NULL;

        END LOOP;
    
  --Ending Statement
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wvers || ' ----'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- Run on ' || wcur_Tim);
END;
/

SHOW ERRORS;
```

To execute, I have to compile the 'Extract_column' procedure and then 'Extract_tables' procedure, then I run the tables procedure to generate my output.

How can I format my current output in a way that it exactly matches the picture above?

Comment: Instead of rolling your own - reinventing the wheel - why not just use dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Comment: I basically want to determine what is the datatype of the current row. Something like: `IF (currentrow.data_type = varchar || currentrow.data_type = char ){ do something}.` I am just not sure how to implement it in Oracle plsql

Comment: No, according to your opening statement, you want to "generate a Create Table Statement.".  Now you are getting hung up on a technical detail in trying to achieve that end by using the results of querying some data dictionary tables.  A typical x-y problem.  Step back and look at your ultimate goal, as you stated "generate a Create Table Statement.".  And dbms_metadata was created by oracle to to that very thing.